# Specialisation with Composite Primary Key

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, erd, datamodel

Situation is that I have a table containing customer_ids, along with 2 other attributes. Customer_ids repeat in this table, due to the customers being able to own multiples of the other attributes.

IE:

```
CUST_ID     ATTR1      ATTR2
01          AAAAA      ZZZZZ
01          BBBBB      XXXXX
02          YYYYY      WWWWW
```

Specialisations always inherit there Parents Primary key, in this case Cust_id. However, making that a primary key here obviously does not work... is it appropriate to use a composite key within the specialisation?

Any other feedback or ideas welcomed!

Comment: This does not look like a customer table then. What does the rest of the data model look like?

Comment: Probably not. Assuming the attributes may change (even slowly) over time, such a composite key is not a good candidate for a PK. In most cases, a PK should be a value that is almost guaranteed to never change. In your example, if you need a PK on this table (perhaps because other tables may refer to it), you may be best off adding a system-generated numeric PK - use a sequence.

Comment: This looks like a multivalued composite attribute table (or two multivalued attributes violating 4NF), not a specialization table.

Comment: So, the other two attributes are a card_number and the other is irrelevant to this. Customers can have more than one of these card numbers. A customer can have 2 types of cards, but only one type of customer can have both. The other can only have one. I hope that makes sense

Comment: @rhys_stubbs. I was not really asking about other attribute, but rather other entities. Do you have a separate customer entity (table)? So back to you original question; A customer_id will only appear twice at most - is that correct? So if ATTR1 is the card type, then the unique key of this table would be (cust_id, attr1)

Comment: @Bobc I have actually resolved this now, I have removed the specialisation and created the relation as its own table. To continue the discussion, customer_id could appear has many times as it likes. But yes you're correct that would have been the unique key. My question was simply can a specialisation can a composite key!